# Can a RDMA write verb cause interrupt on the targeted server?

Tags: interrupt, rdma

Hi i am wondering whether a RDMA write verb can cause interrupt on the targeted server?
i don't think this is how people would use it but i am just curious whether the RDMA can or can't

Answer (score 1):

RDMA write(without immediate) does not have a receive WQE(work queue entry).
Hence, it will not write an entry in to the CQ(completion queue), a CQE is is created mostly for RDMA send or writes with immediate.
If your intension is to trigger an event on the remote host, to consume memory from SGEs after you've written them, you can either issue a send with a solicited bit set or write with immediate, that would trigger an event.